# Display an OGRE mesh and material in RVIZ

Tags: rviz, ogre, collada, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to display an OGRE mesh with a material in RVIZ but I'm having some difficulty. I can display the mesh by itself (without a material) by using the mesh_resource marker message. However, I can't figure out a way to get the material to display as well.

The mesh_resource marker message supports "embedded" materials which I have gotten to work with COLLADA files. Does anyone have suggestions for either converting the ogre mesh/material to a COLLADA .dae file or for getting the ogre mesh/material to work directly?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9770/display-an-ogre-mesh-and-material-in-rviz/) by [Andrew Chambers](https://answers.ros.org/users/435/andrew-chambers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ogre has a script to import ogre meshes into blender. Blender can then export collada.

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Tools%3A+Blender#Ogre_Blender_Import_Script

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 431 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1